# React router configuration

Tags: javascript, react-router

React-router appears to use JSX for configuration.

It would seem that configuration could also be done directly (simply?) in JavaScript.

Did they use JSX because it is clearer, or is there some other benefit?

Example:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Featured}></IndexRoute>
      ...
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer you can use plain objects! Otherwise, the router converts it for you. See the example below:

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: Layout,
  indexRoute: { component: Featured }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} />)
```